# How to use Angular Resolver for a component without route config?

Tags: angular, api, angular-resolver

I am using Angular `Resolver` to prefetch data from the server before showing the route so a page is not loaded empty, we're Ok about this principle.

My question now is how to use the same `Resolver` to prefetch data from server without a route ? To explain more my question here is sketch of my screen :

[image]

On the HeadreComponent of my app I need to make some api-call to get `person.firstName` and `person.lastName` but the header has no defined routes because it's supposed to be shown on  the first page (http:localhost:4200\home).
So I'm not able to use the regular syntax in routes config to call the Resolver like this :

```
{path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, resolve: {personInfos: PersonInfoResolver}}
```

I might be missing something seen that I'm starting Angular development so be kind please :D

Comment: You could make a parent with an empty path and no component, and include your app component as a child of that route. That would make your app component a routed on, along with your header, making it possible to use a resolver.

Comment: @trichetriche could you explain more please ? Do you mean creating a HeaderParentComponent with `{path: '', component: HeaderParentComponent, resolve: {personInfos: PersonInfoResolver}}` ?

Comment: Yes, remove the header from your app component. Make it so that it appears in your routing configuration. Then, you get access to resolvers.

Comment: In this case I think I should do it for the hole transverse components, eg NavigationComponent, FooterComponent, etc ...  Am I right ? 
It will be : `{path: '', component: ParentComponent, resolve: {list all my api resolvers here ...}}` and the html part of my ParentComponent will be like :
`<app-header>
<router-outlet>
<app-footer>`

Comment: Depends on what you expect, but it can be the case yes. If i were you, I would simply load the page without the data first, since the header/footer are pieces of the application that will never move.

Comment: https://dev.to/jdgamble555/preloading-data-in-angular-universal-20lj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I used it what @trichetriche proposed in comment : using a parent component that has a route () to implement the resolvers and then use `@Input()` to pass the data to ChildComponent.